# C++ When writing to a file it only writes the last line not the full body of text?

Tags: c++

I am having an issue in C++ in which a program that I am writing reads a pre-existing text file called `Builders.txt` and then writes the same information into a new text file called `output.txt`, however, when I go to run the program the only line visible in the `output.txt` file is the last line, which is `Tom:90:3.`

Text file

```
Reliable Rover:70:1.
Sloppy Simon:20:4.
Technical Tom:90:3.
```

The expect output from the `output.txt` file would be the file shown above

Body Program

```
int main() {

  readFile();
  writeFile();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Implementation file

```
std::ifstream filereadBuilders("Builders.txt");
std::string input;

void readFile() { //fumction that reads each file. 

  std::vector < std::string > readBuilders;

  //loop to read builders.txt
  while (filereadBuilders >> input) {
    readBuilders.push_back(input);
  }

  std::cout << endl;
}

void writeFile() {

  std::ofstream file("output.txt");
  std::vector < std::string > RAT;
  RAT.push_back(input);

  for (std::string outputFile: RAT) {
    file << outputFile << std::endl;
  }

}
```

I am also having an issue where when it reads/writes, it skips white space. As seen in the expected output file the last line is `Technical Tom:90:3.`, however, my program only returns `Tom:90:3.`, as if its ignoring all white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
std::vector<std::string> RAT;
RAT.push_back(input);
```

you are adding only the last line that was read from the file to `RAT`. It makes sense that only that line is written to the output file.

Suggestion for future coding projects -- avoid global variables as much as possible.

In your case, make sure that `readFile` returns the `vector` of lines to the calling function. Then, pass that data to `writeFile`. While at it, pass the input file to `readFile` and pass the output file to `writeFile` as well.

```
void readFile(std::string const& inputFile,
              std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
   std::ifstream file(inputFile);
   std::string line;

   // Use getline. This makes sure that even whitespaces are read in.
   while(std::getline(file, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

   std::cout << endl;
}

void writeFile(std::string const& outputFile,
               std::vector<std::string> const& lines)
{
   std::ofstream file(outputFile);
   for(std::string const& line: lines)
   {
      file << line << std::endl;
   }
}
```

and call them as

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string inputFile = "Builders.txt";
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";

readFile(inputFile, lines);
writeFile(outputFile, lines);
```

Comment: Passing and returning values from functions is a concept beginners struggle with.

Comment: @john, that seems to point to a deficiency in how programming is taught. I can't relate to the problem since I am a mostly self-taught programmer.